# How to call a function only once (global variable scope)

Tags: php, functions, globals

I have been trying to work out the most effecient way to use functions in WordPress.

I have a big slow function big_slow_function() that ideally is only run once. But I need to use the boolean that is returned by this function throughout my theme files (in header.php, page.php, sidebar.php, footer.php, loop-page.php, functions.php etc).

I am wondering how to do this.

I tried putting this in my functions.php to try and avoid calling big_slow_function() more than once:

```
global $my_important_boolean;

function $get_my_important_boolean()
{
    global $my_important_boolean;

    if ($my_important_boolean == NULL) // if big_slow_function() has not been run yet
        $my_important_boolean = big_slow_function();

    return $my_important_boolean;
}
```

And then I put code like this throughout my theme files:

```
if ($get_my_important_boolean()) {
    // customize content to user
}
```

But the big_slow_function() is still being run every time. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and have found it hard to find good documentation on variable scope in WordPress. Perhaps I need to pass a reference/pointer to the variable?

Any help with this problem is much appreciated as I have been struggling with it for sometime.

Comment: Close-voted as *off-topic*. This is a **PHP/general-programming** question, *not* a **WordPress** question.

Comment: Apologies. I thought the problem had to do with the way Wordpress handled global variables. I was wrong.

Comment: @ChipBennett If you close vote, then you should actually click the vote link.

Comment: @kaiser I disagree. A downvote says that the question itself is bad/low-quality. A close-vote for being off-topic simply indicates that the question belongs elsewhere.

Comment: @ChipBennett I wrote _close_ vote, not _down_ vote... Didn't do that either, right? :)

Comment: @kaiser yes, actually, I did. :)

Comment: @ChipBennett Then we got a bug. I can only read one close vote and this is mine.

Comment: @kaiser apparently so. I observe the same thing.

Comment: @ChipBennet flagged

Comment: Not a bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120896/why-do-close-votes-expire

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
function my_big_function() {

    static $result;

    // Function has already run
    if ( $result !== null )
        return $result;

    // Lot of work here to determine $result
    $result = 'whatever';

    return $result;
}
```

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188994/static-keyword-inside-function

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking. Much appreciated, Geert.

Comment: Just to complement this answer, and also because I don't see any reference to this in any of the comments, `PHP` functions cannot begin with the `$` as that is reserved for `$variables` in PHP.